# Open Network Linux (ONL): kernel source patch

Tags: kernel, compiling, patch

I'm trying to apply some patches on the ONL kernel. Based on a question and its reply, there is a method to apply patches. (The link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opennetworklinux/sXwL3Sz14j4/discussion )

For the sake of simplicity, I tried to apply a small patch. I went through dmesg logs and find the log "Refined TSC clocksource calibration...". This log is just found once in the source code, located in the "arch/x86/kernel/tsc.c".

I have changed this log (add some text to it) and rebuild the ONL exactly based on the method. But no change has happened to that log when I run the rebuilt ONL. So, my questions are:

1) Is it correct to change a text log in the kernel source plainly? Have I missed something here?

2) Has anybody here done any patch on the ONL kernel source? I think something is missed in overall steps to apply patches on ONL kernel.

Best,
Amir